# Kafka last offset increases on application restart

Tags: java, akka, apache-kafka

I have a Java Akka application that reads from Kafka, process the messages and commits manually.

I'm using the High Level consumer of the 0.10.1.1 API.

The strange thing is when I shutdown the application and start it again the offset is a little bigger than the last commit and I cannot find why.

I have only one commit point in the code.

```
else if(message.getClass() == ProcessedBatches.class) {
        try {
            Logger.getRootLogger().info("[" + this.name + "/Reader] Commiting ...");
            ProcessedBatches msg = (ProcessedBatches) message;
            consumer.commitSync(msg.getCommitInfo());
            lastCommitData = msg.getCommitInfo();
            lastCommit = System.currentTimeMillis();
        } catch (CommitFailedException e) {
            Logger.getRootLogger().info("[" + this.name + "/Reader] Failed to commit... Last commit: " + lastCommit + " | Last batch: " + lastBatch + ". Current uncommited messages: " + uncommitedMessages);
            self().tell(HarakiriMessage.getInstance(), self());
        }
    }
```

After commit I save the offsets HashMap in the lastCommitData in order to debug it.

Then I've added a shutdown hook to print the lastCommitData variable to check what is the last offset commited for each partition.

```
  Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(() -> {
        String output = 
                "############## SHUTTING DOWN CONSUMER ############### \n" + 
                lastCommitData+"\n";
        System.out.println(output);
    }));
```

Also I have a consumer rebalance listener to check start position of each partition when consumer starts.

```
new ConsumerRebalanceListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPartitionsRevoked(Collection<TopicPartition> collection) {}

        @Override
        public void onPartitionsAssigned(Collection<TopicPartition> collection) {
            for (TopicPartition p:collection
                 ) {
                System.out.println("Starting position "+p.toString()+":" + consumer.position(p));
            }
            coordinator.setRebalanceTimestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());
        }
    });
```

Example for one partition:

Offset before shutdown:               3107169023

Offset when partition assigned:       3107180350

As you can see is almost 10K messages between each.

The consumer properties are the following:

```
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("bootstrap.servers", bootstrapServers);
    props.put("group.id", group_id);
    props.put("enable.auto.commit", "false");
    props.put("auto.commit.interval.ms", "100000000");
    props.put("session.timeout.ms", "10000");
    props.put("key.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
    props.put("value.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArrayDeserializer");
    props.put("max.poll.records", "40000");
    props.put("auto.offset.reset", "latest");
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: How long is it from when you shutdown to when you restart the app. The default offset retention period is 24 hours.

Comment: It doesn't really matter, it can stay down for 1 hour or 5 minutes. I will still get the same increase.

Comment: Do you have more than one consumer in the consumer group (same group.id)

Answer (score 1):

Am I correct in thinking you base your assumed "Offset before shutdown: 3107169023" on what your shutdown hook prints?

If so, I see 2 potentials issues.

When you register your shutdown hook you are closing over the lastCommitData field.

Since you are accessing it from another thread, the shutdown hook thread, is the field declared volatile? Otherwise you may be printing a stale value.

Also, java.lang.Runtime.addShutdownHook says:

> When the virtual machine begins its shutdown sequence it will start all registered shutdown hooks in some unspecified order and let them run concurrently

so there is no guarantee that your consumer won't manage to commit offsets further after your shutdown hook has already printed the lastCommitData value.

I suggest you inspect Kafka to check what are the actual committed offsets after your app shuts down to be sure.

Comment: Hmm, it might happen, I will look at the offsets after shutdown. Didn't know that things could happen after shutdown hook, or that data might be stalled.

Answer (score 0):

Check retention policy of our topic
 it maybe the case when you start back your consumer, the last committed offset might have been purged from the partition and the consumer will move forward to the latest offset for that partition.

Comment: Is not that either, I'm at the end of the queue and the retention for that topic is 4 days. Also is not starting from the end of the queue, just a little further than the last commited position. Not very much, just a little. This is a consumer for QPS of our endpoints and on the chart I can clearly see the drop when I restart it.

Comment: The Kafka consumer offset topic has a different retention period from the individual topics. Default is 1 day.

Comment: I'm restarting the consumer in about 5-10  minutes  from the shutdown, also it does not matter if I wait 5 minutes or 1 hour.

Answer (score -1):

When you poll Kafka using the Consumer API, it reads from the last consumed offset in the partition. There must be other consumers in the system which must have got the partitions which were previously been consumed by the instance which you just stopped - thus the latest offset would have changed. Since you know which offset you were at before exiting, you would need to save it to some durable store - use the `ConsumerRebalanceListener#onPartitionsRevoked` for this. Read that offset when you restart the consumer process and point your consumer to start from there - do this by calling `seek(partition, offset)` in `ConsumerRebalanceListener#onPartitionsAssigned`

Comment: Well, that's the only consumer for that topic with that consumer group, and as far as I know when I close the consumer and start it again it should start from the last commited offset instead of the last consumed offset. I could save the offset and seek, but if I'm not wrong I should not be in charge of that in a High level consumer.

Comment: The API gives you the option of saving and seeking the offset - so that's a valid path. Arguing about right or wrong is useless - its about requirements & use cases and what's appropriate